# Django-How to retrieve posts data of logged in user friends

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am working on a Social network project!!
It has models that saves User data ,Friends data and Posts data

```
Users -> User Info
Friends -> User friends
Media -> All Posts from users
```

How do i get the posts of friends of logged-in user .

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    """Model for saving relationship of user and friends"""
    request_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='current_user')
    friend_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_friend')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

class MediaDB(models.Model):
    """All User Feed Items"""
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    m_url = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    likes_count = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you posted your models.

Comment: You need to edit the question and post the code there, properly formatted.

Comment: I've done that!!Thank you!!!

Comment: Is the User model the standard built-in one from django.contrib.auth?

Comment: yes!!! @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the posts for the friends of the logged-in user by following the relationships:

```
friends_posts = MediaDB.objects.filter(username__user_friend__request_id=request.user)
```

Note that some of your naming is a bit odd; the `username` field on MediaDB points to the user, so it should be called just `user`, and the fields on Friends are even stranger; there is no "request" involved, and they are not "ids", and the reverse relations don't at all explain what they are.

Comment: Well!!!Thanks for your answer......Reverse relations indicate that the request_id and friend_id are users and that points to users in User model!!!Well the fields of Friends are used in that way to understand conveniently. @Daniel Roseman